# JS - async request - Immediately return this expression instead of assigning it to the temporary variable

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I have the following:

```
  const getData = async (): Promise<any> => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://xxxx`).then(res => res.data);
    const names = response?.map((inside: any) => {
      return {
        firstName: inside?.firstName,
        surName: inside?.surName.toUpperCase(),
      }
    })
    return names;
  }
```

SonarQube flags this as '*Immediately return this expression instead of assigning it to the temporary variable "names*".'

I understand there may be a better way to refactor this, but why does it not like assigning to a temporary variable and how would you refactor this to just return the expression?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `return response?.map(....` ??

Comment: *"...but why does it not like assigning to a temporary variable..."* I can't think of a good reason. *"...and how would you refactor this to just return the expression?"* I wouldn't. I would turn off whatever silly rule is saying to do that. The temporary variable does absolutely no harm, and makes debugging easier.

Comment: @T.J Crowder - Good point

Comment: But unrelated to your actual question: There's no reason to *mix* `async`/`await` and a `.then` above: https://pastebin.com/x9QW8Vp1

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough, it's just this:

```
  const getData = async (): Promise<any> => await axios.get(`https://xxxx`)
    .then(res => res.data?.map((inside: any) => {
      return {
        firstName: inside?.firstName,
        surName: inside?.surName.toUpperCase(),
      }
    }));
  }
```

I did take the liberty to remove a redundant `return` statement as well and move the `.map()` function inside the `.then` scope, since this seemed to relate to the received data.

Comment: If you refactor it like that, there's no reason for it to be an `async` function at all. But doing the above may make error stack traces harder to read.

Comment: Also, this doesn't answer the question: *"why does it not like assigning to a temporary variable"*

Comment: There's still the need for it to be async, as the promise should still get awaited and returned. As for the SolarQube warning, that's merely some configuration in some styling tool. I do agree that error stack traces may be more difficult now to read, but with a `.catch`, that should be resolved already.

Comment: *"There's still the need for it to be async"* No, there isn't. If you're going to use the old style with `.then`, you can literally just remove the `async` and the `await`. (But I wouldn't. I'd remove the `.then` instead.) *"I do agree that error stack traces may be more difficult now to read, but with a .catch, that should be resolved already."* No, catching in that function would be an anti-pattern. Errors should propagate to where they can be usefully handled.